# Not Storing the value of silver light control in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have used the silverlight control in CRM 2011.It also published on form but the problem is i am not able to store its value in CRM.In general if we create any field and publish that field in Form then its value will be stored after clicking on Save button.and after that when we open that record,we can see control value that was stored previously.but in my case i published that silver light control on form but after save the record when i click on Record i cant see its value again.means silverlight control value was not going to stored in CRM.I have just simply used the textbox of silverlight...

Comment: How are you 'binding' the Silverlight text box to the CRM data field it represents?  For example, are you reading a CRM field to populate the Silverlight control on load, and then copying the value back to the CRM field on save?  Or are you using the REST service to achieve this?

Comment: Nothing I just put the silverlight control textbox to CRM Form...now i want such functionality that if i am going to click on Save the value of silverlight control should be saved...i have taken textbox contol of silverlight now after clicking on Save button the value of silverlight control textbox should be saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call a JavaScript function on your form from Silverlight. Take a look at [the HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for communicating between the page and Silverlight.  There's [an example in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of registering and calling a JavaScript function from Silverlight.

In Silverlight it looks like:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("myJSMethod", myParam);
```

Comment: This is essentially the answer OP is looking for.  Nothing will happen with values entered into Silverlight unless there's some code to link it back to values on the form.  Chris' code shows you how do this in the direction of Silverlight to JavaScript, and if you reference the Silverlight control in JavaScript you can go the other way too (i.e. calling Silverlight methods from JavaScript).